# SQL Server: changing collation of selected columns

Tags: sql-server, ssms, collation

In SQL Server how to change a collation of only selected columns? Is there a way to do that using SQL Server Management Studio?

I was googling around but what I found where instructions how to change collation of a database not a specific column.

**EDIT:**

So I found this bit of SQL to change column's collation:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
   ALTER COLUMN Column1 [TYPE] COLLATE [NewCollation]
```

Still is there a way to do that using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Right-click on table name -> Design, then select column and go to Collation in column properties tab (inside **Table Designer** group).

Comment: "Collate xxx" comes before "NOT NULL" in `ALTER` / `CREATE` column specification, BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on table name and choose Design. Then select column and go to Collation in column properties tab (inside **Table Designer** group).

[image]